# Load images using AssetImagePath result in Lang binding MvxException: PropertyName must start with letter

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In a simple MvvmCross project, I am trying to load an image from Asset/image.png on Android. I have searched for this and found that this is one way that should work.

The Image is set as AndroidAsset and CopyAlways and resides in the Asset folder.
In the ViewModel I have this:

```
private string _image = "image.png";
    public string Image
    { 
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Image); }
    }
```

In the axml

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    local:MvxBind="{'AssetImagePath':{'Path':'Image'}}" />
```

And in the Setup

```
 protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ImageView>("AssetImagePath",
                                                       imageView => new MvxImageViewImageTargetBinding(imageView));
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
```

When I run the app, nothing is displayed and the log reports:

```
Problem parsing Lang binding MvxException: PropertyName must start with letter - position 0 in {'AssetImagePath':{'Path':'Image'}} - char {
```

What does that error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using old pre-Swiss style json binding. Switch to Swiss - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding section on "mvvmcross data binding"

also, please be aware of issue https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/372 - linked to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/311 (which contains a workaround)